# Configure Quartz for interval and different starting hours

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I've been looking for this for a while now, but I didn't find a way to do what I want.

I have a Web Page in which a user can plan some actions during a week.
For example:
On monday morning, from 8:00 to 10:00, do this...
On tuesday afternoon, from 1:30 to 2:00, do that...

Well, I would like that my Java program automatically launch the actions for the periods that the user selected. And, during these time intervals, repeat the action every X minutes. (Should be configurable)

What I thought was setting up Quartz with Cron scheduler. However, I don't know how to handle half hours...

More precisely:

This will work for my first example (repeat every 5 minutes between 8 to 10):

**0 0/5 8-10 * * MON**

But how to handle the second example? (Starting at 1:30 but repeat the action every 5 minutes??)

Thanks !

Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I found an answer to my needs: DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder !

Here is an example for answer my need:

```
DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
                                                                .startingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(13, 30, 0))
                                                                .endingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(14, 0, 0))
                                                                .onDaysOfTheWeek(1)
                                                                .withIntervalInMinutes(5);
```

Problem solved 
Philippe